# Build subproject in Spark with sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, build, sbt

I want to build subproject in Spark with sbt. I found this example and it works

```
$ ./build/sbt -Phive -Phive-thriftserver  (build)
sbt (spark)> project hive (switch to subproject)
sbt (hive)> testOnly *.HiveQuerySuite -- -t foo ( run test case)
```

However, I tried the following but it does not build but quit
`./build/sbt -mllib`

I do not know how does the author figure out `-Phive -Phive-thriftserver`. I cannot find this in Spark source code.

I just want to do the exact same thing as the example but with a different subproject.

---

This is not asking how to use `projects` to print out all available projects.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the project scope:

```
./build/sbt mllib/compile
```

refer to: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Scopes.html